# cvs2svn Migration

Tags: python, unix, cvs2svn

We want to move a project from CVS Repository to SVN  Repository ?

For this we have installed cvs2svn-2.4.0 in our unix tomcat server.
We are having python utility 2.3.3 under /usr/local/bin and  libstdc++.so.6 under /usr/local/lib.

Now when we are running cvs2svn command from cvs2svn-2.4.0, we are getting the below error:-
**ld.so.1: python: fatal: libstdc++.so.5: open failed: No such file or directory**.

My Questions are :-

1. Is only python 2.4 required for CVS2SVN or any higher ver of Python can also be installed ?
2. Presently Python 2.3.3 is present under /usr/local/bin, is it to be placed under /usr/bin? both the paths /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin are set as PATH Environment Variable  ?
3. Will libstdc++.so.6 compatible with python 2.4 or higher or do we have to install libstdc++.so.5 ?
4. libstdc++.so.6 is placed under usr/local/lib, do we have to place it under /usr/lib, then can it work ?
5. In Env Variable PATH, both /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib are not present , do we have to export these directories under Env Path Variable ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Python needed by cvs2svn is documented in [the requirements section](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html#reqs) of the cvs2svn documentation:

> Python 2, version 2.4 or later. See http://www.python.org/. (cvs2svn does not work with Python 3.x.)

The same section also describes some other requirements that you will need.

The Python interpreter can be placed in your PATH, or alternatively you can invoke cvs2svn using an explicit python interpreter like

```
/path/to/my/python /path/to/my/cvs2svn [args]
```

The rest of your questions are not about cvs2svn but rather about how to install a working Python on your platform, which you haven't even specified.